# Is there a way to use Azure Power Shell to redeploy an ACI using a YAML file?

Tags: azure, powershell, yaml, azure-container-instances

I would like to re-deploy an Azure container instance using a YAML file. This command below using CLI works:

```
az container create --resource-group <resource group> --file <yaml file>
```

However, I would like to perform the same but as an Azure Power Shell script. Could anyone provide insight on this please?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

***AFAIK, We can not pass it with PowerShell script instead of CLI ,Tried in different ways and its not possible currently.***

Instead of that you can use below PowerShell `cmdlts` by which you [**`can create container`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-quickstart-powershell#create-a-container).

```
New-AzContainerGroup -ResourceGroupName myResourceGroup -Name mycontainer -Image mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/iis:nanoserver -OsType Windows -DnsNameLabel aci-demo-win
```

Here is the list of parameter mentioned which is supported by PowerShell:[**`New-AzContainerGroup`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.containerinstance/new-Azcontainergroup?view=azps-8.1.0)

**Alternatively**, You can run azure powershell script through YAML release pipeline as mentioned in this [***SO THREAD***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66275472) by @*Tarta* .

For more information please refer this **Blog**|[***Deploying Azure Container Instances using YAML***](https://www.sqlshack.com/deploying-azure-container-instances-using-yaml/#:%7E:text=To%20execute%20the%20YAML%20script,parameter%20%E2%80%93file%20for%20container%20deployment.&text=You%20get%20JSON%20script%20output,portal%20to%20verify%20the%20containers.) .